How would tides work on a habitable moon orbiting a gas giant?
Lets say, there is a habitable Earth-like moon orbiting around a gas giant, which orbits around an F-type star. The gas giant is slightly smaller than Jupiter, and the moon is slightly smaller than Earth. How seasons would work is that the moon orbits slowly around the gas giant, I don't know if it might be accurate or not but lets just see.
There would be "months", one full rotation around the planet, and "years", or "cycles", one full rotation around the sun. At the coldest parts of the month, the gas giant will block out the sun. This monthly eclipse will last for days, until it moves away. And at around the hottest part of the month, the gas giant will move to the opposite of where the moon is facing the sun, and it will be the biggest and fullest at that time.
The moon should orbit far away from it's planet just enough so that it won't be irradiated into a inhabitable volcanic hellscape like Io, but it should also be close enough so that the gas giant may always block out the sun every month. There are also two other major moons orbiting around the gas giant, one is about the size of Titan, and one is about the size of Europa.
Let's get to the important part. I am just asking this because I want to see how the tides and climates would look like on a habitable moon based on the information above, considering that the moon generates its own gravitational field, the other two moons do not. And of course the gas giant itself has its own large gravitational field. So, depending on the information, would the moon just have abnormally high and low tides? And how would this affect precipitation levels and weather patterns in general?

(a) If you roll your mouse over the [tag:science-based] and [tag:science-fiction] tags, you'll discover they're mutually exclusive. You must delete one of them. It's always wise to read tag wikis. (b) You are allowed to ask one and only one question. I'd advise deleting your last sentence. It's so broad and climate is so complex that it's not answerable without a LOT of detail you haven't provided anyway. Please carefully read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] to better understand our limitations. Thanks.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

as an extra note along with the answer I gave: "considering that the moon generates its own gravitational field, the other two moons do not"  is literally impossible given how gravity works, the two other moons will have a gravitational field so long as they have any mass greater than zero. I just interpretted this to mean that their gravity is too small to have a noticable affect on the tides.

"At the coldest parts of the month, the gas giant will block out the sun. This monthly eclipse will last for days, until it moves away." No, it won't. The eclipse will last about two hours.

No tide from the Gas Giant
Due to your Earth-like moon being a moon, it's pretty much 100% guranteed to be tidally locked to its parent. Calculated using THIS FORMULA, Inputting the masses of Jupiter and Earth, with a distance of 300,000km (which is right outside Jupiter's radiation belt), it reveals that the moon will tidally lock <1 month after it first forms. Tidal locking is basically inevitable no matter what units you input for the planet or moon orbit, because if it was far enough away to not lock, it would also be far enough away to no longer be a moon. Therefore, when standing on the surface, the position of the Gas Giant in the sky will always remain the same, and the tides will not be noticable.
HOWEVER Solar Tides still exist, and the moon would still experience them.
From this video on the subject he provides a calculator which includes an option for habitable moons. You can play around with the numbers yourself, but when putting in the previous numbers, assuming your Gas Giant is as far from the sun as Jupiter, the Sun would cause tides of around 0.00032meters, which happens to be almost imperceptible anyways. If you want bigger tides in your world, you might consider moving the planet closer to the sun, but make sure not to cook the planet obviously.
Hopefully these links are useful to you. Given the info in the post, I had to assume a lot, but you should be able to modify the equations to your personal liking.

(1) Tidally locked does not mean that the position of the primary in the sky stays the same. See the animation in this question on Astronomy SE. (2) Long story short, for the primary to stay put in the sky and thus cause no tides, the orbit of the secondary must be perfectly circular and the axis of rotation of the secondary must be perpendicular on its orbital plane. (3) But the first condition is impossible when there are more than two bodies in the system. (4) As a practical example, consider the massive tidal heating experienced by Io.

@AlexP good find w/ the animation. In that case I would probably agree with the other guy that the question is too complex. For the Moon's case it looks like earth moves by 10-ish degrees, so if OPs moon is similar I think the tides would be at least 4KM up and down.
Got this by multiplying the total Planetary tide (54km) from the calculator tool I linked by 8% (if the planet moves by 10 degrees, and a tidal cycle is 90 degrees, 1/9th of Earth tidal cycle is ~8% rise in water level).
ofc, no way to know what the real numbers would be until OP give more info. Very complex question

(*continued) I got the 8% tide thing from HERE after i remembered that tides aren't linear.
